# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'page_id' cannot be null laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel-5

i am using laravel 5.2 and jquery ajax

I working on a application on which i am passing a larger data of post through ajax. but for larger data i am getting this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'page_id' cannot be null laravel 5
```

here are my php.ini settings which i have tried

```
max_input_vars = 9000
post_max_size=30M
```

here is my code of jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
      url : url+'/ajax-saveall-Collectionpost',
      type : 'POST',
      data : {'posts_data':posts_data,'page_id':page_id,'page_name':page_name,'collection_id':collection_id},
      dataType : 'JSON',
      beforeSend: function(data) {
            $("#loading").show()
      },
      success : function(data) {
             $("#loading").hide()},
      error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
     });
```

Here is my laravel controller function

```
public function saveall_Collectionpost(){
    $posts_data = Input::get('posts_data');
    $page_id = Input::get('page_id');
    $page_name = Input::get('page_name');
    $collection_id = Input::get('collection_id');

    if($this->user_id !== false){
        foreach ($posts_data as $key => $value) {

            $this->save_fav_post($page_id,$page_name,$posts_data[$key]['id'],$collection_id,$value);    
        }
        $return['error'] = false;
    }else{
        $return['error'] = 'login';
    }
```

the problem which i am facing here is this that i am losting the data for larager data in php controller function

when i `print_r the data of $posts_data array` then it gives me only 66 index of array however if i got my chrome network tab and check the form data which is being passed from jquery ajax request then that data has 115 index of array also the page_id value is being passed in the form data to from jquery ajax request but if i `echo the $page_id then i see no value`.

then it means values are being passed but they are getting lost in laravel controller function when i tries them to get using like this

```
$posts_data = Input::get('posts_data');
$page_id = Input::get('page_id');
```

Comment: remove `dataType : 'JSON',` and done

Comment: @RakeshSharma 
 
i have tried but i am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Remove `dataType : 'JSON',` from ajax post code. cause you are sending json string to function which is not considered as separate variable. so remove this, or parse your json in function first then set it to vars.
Also make sure your `page_id` is not blank.

Comment: let me try it please

Comment: @usama check you're posting on correct url then print your post data